# Can Azure function communicate with Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I have two regions with virtual machines deployed.

1. West Europe
2. Cental US

**Data Flow**

1. User types `www.somethingdotcom` in browser.
2. `Request` goes to `Azure front door`
3. `Azure front door` sends a request to a nearby location (Azure function-deployed in both regions)
4. Azure function talks to `master data` from `db` or `cache` to GET `load balancer address` (private IP).
5. Now question is, can azure function redirect request to `target` application gateway?

I want to redirect the requests to right VM based on mapping specified in  `Cache`

Is this architecture help? I suspect on communication between `Azure function` and `Application Gateway`.

[image]

Comment: I wouldnt see a reason why you could not do that. You could probably achieve the same with 1 API Management - replacing both, the Function as well as the AppGW

Comment: How APIM will help?  where do you place APIM? could u write the data flow?

Comment: Front Door -> APIM. APIM inbound policy does your logic, set-backend based on that -> forward to backend

Comment: backend for APIM can be application gateway?

Comment: sure thing. but I'm not sure if you even still need appgw - but that depends on what you do with it

Comment: app gateway will do health probe to active VM. it will send data to ACTIVE "On" VM. I want to distribute the request to different REGIONS based on "request" initiated location.

Comment: As far as the APIM is concerned it can register an api hosted on a URL. As long as the App Gateway (I am assuming you want to use it as a Load Balancer) can front the actual resource with a URL, an APIM can point to it.

Comment: @Rupendra  flow diagram could help.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram below does not show any network related detail around the VMs e.g. the vNet/subnet configuration, etc.

[image: Image Description]

The details of an App Gateway are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works).
List of policies supported by APIM are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies#ProxyPolicies).

Also, unless you have a specific reason to stay in a VM, and if you are just deploying an API or a website, moving to an App Service will reduce the amount of work you would need to do to expose the HTTP endpoints.